# Increase limits with Jetty: URI is too large >8192

Tags: java, eclipse, jetty, jax-rs

I am running a Java webservice (JAX-RS) with command: `java -jar ws.jar`. The app has been built on Eclipse.

When I receive a GET request, I get the following error:

```
org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - URI is too large >8192
```

I tried changing uncommenting and adding a "0" at the end of these lines at `/opt/jett/start.ini`, but I get same error.

```
## Max response content write length that is buffered (in bytes)
jetty.httpConfig.outputAggregationSize=81920

## Max request headers size (in bytes)
jetty.httpConfig.requestHeaderSize=81920

## Max response headers size (in bytes)
jetty.httpConfig.responseHeaderSize=81920
```

I am aware of the risks of augmenting URI size, but I really need to do it for a research test.

Comment: Are you using jetty-distribution?  Where is your `${jetty.base}`?  Perhaps including the output of `java -jar start.jar --list-config` in your question could help.

Answer (score 0):

This issue comes also when you try to use HTTP POST request with parameters which is too large, and hence URI becomes too large. This is because parameters are appended to URI as in GET request. The easy way is to use, multipart with APIs as mentioned below in the code:

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/video", consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<IngestionResponseDTO> ingestVideo(@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file, @RequestPart("jsonMetadata") String videoIngestionDTO){...}
```

Python code to upload file with request body is as follows:

```
        with open(filepath, 'rb') as file:
        files = {'file': file, 'jsonMetadata': json.dumps(body_data)}
        response = requests.post(
            f"http://{self.upload_host}:{self.upload_port}/upload",
            headers=headers, files=files)
```